# User control Changing size when In ViewBox

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-8.1, viewbox

I have a user control(Windows 8.1 app) which I have developed using PATH vector control. I have put it inside a ViewBox . The problem is , when I change the screen resolution or even orientation , the Control either get reduced or get too much big.

I want to give it a fixed size so whatever the screen resolution is or orientation is, It shouldnt increase the size .

The XAML for my user control is

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="controlMagnifier.MagnifierUsercontrol"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:controlMagnifier"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"

    d:DesignWidth="200">


    <Canvas x:Name="controlCanvas" x:FieldModifier="public"   >
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform>

            </RotateTransform>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>

        <Grid Height="250" Width="176" Canvas.Left="23" Canvas.Top="40" >

                <Border x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="imgBorder" Width="150" CornerRadius="50,50,50,50" Margin="13,20,13,90">
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="image1"    />
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>


            <TextBlock x:Name="txtreading" Height="30" Width="80" Margin="0,-145,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red"  FontSize="20" Text="ABC" TextAlignment="Center" />
            <!--<Image Height="120" Width="150" Margin="0,-50,0,0" Source="Assets/SmallLogo.scale-100.png" ></Image>-->
            <Path x:Name="MagnifyTip"  Data="m 422.67516,254.62099 c -54.00107,0 -97.94018,-42.99659 -97.94018,-95.82439 0,-52.83449 43.93911,-95.824384 97.94018,-95.824384 53.98741,0 97.93335,42.989894 97.93335,95.824384 0,52.8278 -43.94594,95.82439 -97.93335,95.82439 z m -4.5e-4,-201.388003 c -59.74605,0 -108.33864,48.616303 -108.33864,108.338643 0,56.09938 81.0924,116.80009 104.5378,191.74948 0.50401,1.61877 2.01605,2.72166 3.71189,2.7098 1.70178,-0.0237 3.1901,-1.13847 3.67039,-2.76909 C 449.00187,276.46834 531.00741,217.73624 531.01334,161.55977 531.00741,101.84929 482.4089,53.232987 422.67471,53.232987 Z" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" UseLayoutRounding="False" Height="227" Width="171" />


        </Grid>
    </Canvas>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: "I want to give it a fixed size". Then why do you put it in  a Viewbox? Please show the XAML where the UserControl is actually used.

Comment: I want to put in into viewbox becuase I have to handle different screen resolutions too and the user control position to. When I am not using Viewbox and my testing device is in Landscape mode , I am getting my user control where I click , but when I am doing landscape , the image is cropping and the user control in not appearing at the clicked area .. see my code   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CCW5N6MTHoY25rUGV6ZW9MMVE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If the *only* thing in the Viewbox is your user control, just get rid of the Viewbox, it stretches and scales the content by design!

If you have various controls in your Viewbox but you you only want *some* of them to resize, you might be better changing your layout to use a grid and only wrapping the stuff you *want* to resize in a Viewbox.

Here is an example of a 3x3 grid with 6 textboxes, 5 fixes size, 1 dynamic (in a Viewbox):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Fixed Size"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Fixed Size"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Fixed Size"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Fixed Size"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Fixed Size"></TextBox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBox Text="Dynamic"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: No It wont help me ! I just have one image box and the user control has to come over it .